# I am loading image in Glide but Glide not working if url contains space

Tags: android, android-glide, image-loading

I am loading image in glide having spacing in it but facing some issue.

I remove white spaces but image not loaded.

```
image.replaceAll(" ", "%20"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation [says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), that replaceAll() method doesn't modify your string, but ***returns*** a new modified string. So you need to use it like this:

```
image = image.replaceAll(" ", "%20"))
```